# How do you use Java to call the Rhino Javascript interpreter?

Tags: java, javascript, rhino, serverside-javascript

is there any example on using java method to call rhino-javascript function and return it back to java?  The only example i found for rhino is only typing command on the rhino shell.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure, here's the [Rhino embedding tutorial](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino/Embedding_tutorial).  I've done this in the past and it works very well.  You'll want to scroll down to [this section](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino/Embedding_tutorial#usingJSObjs).

Comment: Sadly, links are not working anymore. Try https://github.com/graalvm/graal-js-jdk11-maven-demo